# Not able to require 'pp' or 'ap' libraries in rspec formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here's my custom formatter:

```
require 'pp'
require 'ap'
require "rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter"

    def example_passed(example)
        super(example)
        output.print success_color('.')

        ap example
    end

    def example_pending(example)
        super(example)
        output.print pending_color('*')
    end

    def example_failed(example)
        super(example)
        output.print failure_color('F')
    end

    def dump_summary(duration, example_count, failure_count, pending_count)
        output.print 'Yep, everything\'s all finished'
    end

end
```

I'm making my own rspec formatter, and there's a lot of really informative data in the `example` hash.

Look at my `example_passed` method where I'm printing it to the screen. However, this prints  it as a huge, unassailable wall of text which makes writing the code to access these values nigh impossible.

I've required `pp`, and have tried to `pp example`. Doesn't do anything, huge wall of text.
I've installed and required `ap` (awesome_print) and tried to `ap example`. Still stuck with this huge wall of text.

I'm getting no error messages saying that either library can't be required. Is this something to do with the complexity of `example`? Is it more than a mere multidimensional hash in some way?

Here's the behemoth itself:

```
#<RSpec::Core::Example:0x0000010576fbf0 @example_block=#<Proc:0x0000010576fd58@/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:7>, @options={}, @example_group_class=RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1, @metadata={:example_group=>{:example_group=>{:description_args=>["my group"], :caller=>["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:300:in `set_it_up'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:245:in `subclass'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'", "/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'"], :file_path=>"./spec/example_spec.rb", :line_number=>3}, :description_args=>["correct pi"], :caller=>["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:300:in `set_it_up'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:245:in `subclass'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'", "/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `module_eval'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `subclass'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'", "/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'"], :file_path=>"./spec/example_spec.rb", :line_number=>4}, :example_group_block=>#<Proc:0x0000010534ef58@/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:4>, :description_args=>["should be right"], :caller=>["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/metadata.rb:187:in `for_example'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:81:in `initialize'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:66:in `new'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:66:in `it'", "/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `module_eval'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `subclass'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'", "/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `module_eval'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `subclass'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'", "/Users/jonathanhurley/Documents/rails/treebook/spec/example_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'"], :description=>"should be right", :execution_result=>{:started_at=>2013-12-02 15:51:51 +0000, :status=>"passed", :finished_at=>2013-12-02 15:51:51 +0000, :run_time=>0.006028}}, @exception=nil, @example_group_instance=nil, @pending_declared_in_example=false, @around_each_hooks=[#<RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook:0x00000102ff7cd0 @block=#<Proc:0x00000100f18758@/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:49>, @options={}>]>
```

Comment: Did you intend to share a different piece of code? This just looks like the default ProgressFormatter.

Comment: Hello again! I'm just getting to grips with things, it pretty much is the default formatter! Slightly different though

Comment: But you said you are "printing it to the screen" in `example_passed` and getting a wall of text. I don't see where you're printing anything but the `.`.

Comment: "ap example" It's a method used by the awesome_print gem to print to the console.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I just missed that ...   Hang on a sec.

Comment: Does `pp` work to print (say) `[1,2,3]` differently than `puts` does in your spec?